# Facebook Share Button cut on mobile share dialog

Tags: android, facebook, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I'm developing a cross platform app with phonegap, and I have a Facebook share dialog, but when the popup opens the share button is cut.

I'm using [Apache Cordova Facebook Plugin](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin) to open the native share dialog, and this only happens on Android devices and with a language which the 'share' word is too long, like Portuguese.

You know how I can fix this?

Thank you

[image: Device Screenchost]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you using this phonegap plugin instead  Apache Cordova Facebook Plugin

https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin

Comment: Thanks @Dato, I'll definitely try this plugin!